# Can't use `ORG` in emu8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16, directive, emu8086

Compile the following code with emu8086, and the program will always be filling in numbers to the data segment, without executing `org`.

```
data segment 
    Count db 0AH 
    org 3500h
    StuId db 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0   
    org 3600h
    Dest db 10 dup(0)
data ends
code segment 
    assume cs:code, ds:data
start:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov cl, Count
    mov ch, 00h   
    lea si, STuId
    lea di, Dest
next:
    mov al, [si]
    mov [di], al 
    inc si
    inc di
    loop next
    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h
code ends
    end start
```

When I remove `org`, the program executes normally, but then it can't locate within the segment.

Comment: org is a not portable feature, different translator interpret it in own ways and for some architectures it is ignored. Dome accept .org instead.

Comment: It seems that emu8086 doesnt support ASSUME, unless it was changed

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to have those initialized arrays at the specified offsets within the *data* segment, and `ORG` doesn't work for you, then just bridge the gap by filling the void with zeroes:

```
data segment 
    Count db 0AH 
          db 3500h-1 dup(0)
    StuId db 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0
          db 3600h-(3500h+10) dup(0)
    Dest  db 10 dup(0)
data ends
```

A drawback of the above code is that your program gets very big. An alternative solution has the array stored in the *code* segment and then copies its elements to offset 3500h of the *data* segment. Your copy can remain as before.
Also possible would be to combine both copies in one loop, or not copy to 3500h at all, if all you need is the final array at 3600h. Since all of this is about learning assembly language, why don't you try them all!

```
data segment 
    Count dw 10
data ends
code segment 
  start:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax

    xor bx, bx
More:
    mov al, cs:StuId[bx]   <<<< cs: segment override prefix
    mov [3500h+bx], al
    inc bx
    cmp bx, 10
    jb  More
    
    mov cx, Count
    mov si, 3500h
    mov di, 3600h
next:
    mov al, [si]
    mov [di], al 
    inc si
    inc di
    loop next
    mov ah, 4Ch
    int 21h

    StuId db 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0   
code ends
end start
```

`mov al, cs:StuId[bx]` uses a `cs:` segment override prefix. This tells the CPU to fetch the elements from your *StuId* array in the *code* segment. Without that prefix, `mov al, StuId[bx]` would fetch the values from the *data* segment.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped me. As a beginner of assembly language, I would like to ask if it is possible to specify the memory address at the beginning of the data segment. I want to load the number at 0000:3500h and then copy it to 0000:3600h.

Comment: @wikizzz You can not 'load' the array at the absolute address 0000:3500h. All data defined in the *data* segment of your program is loaded, along with the rest of the program, at an address that the loader (DOS) chose. That's the reason why you have to write `mov ax, data` `mov ds, ax` before you can start using the items from the *data* segment. Moreover absolute addresses like 0000:3500h and 0000:3600h could contain parts of the DOS kernel, something you don't want to overwrite.